# Unable to open files on Windows Partition from Ubuntu

Tags: wubi, encoding

I installed Ubuntu through WUBI.
I can see that the windows drive is mounted under `/host` and I can see all of the files, but I am unable to open many of the files properly. Simple files like text files and html files look like junk. Appears to be an encoding problem to me. Has anyone faced the issue and is there a solution?

Comment: Is the file encoding UTF-8 or ANSI? What encoding are you trying to read it as?

Comment: There are several files, HTML and TXT files .. I did not check all, but many of them are UTF-8.

Comment: Make sure you're opening them with the correct encoding in your text editor

Comment: I use sublime text and Forced it to open the files as UTF 8 but it still failed. Could it be because of some disc encryption (just guessing that I might be having an encryption set by my employer automatically).

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, it was only the files which were under 'my documents' in windows 7 do not open correctly. I moved the files which I needed to a different temp folder in the root C:\ and then I can access them correctly from ubuntu.